# Embedding Movie in Quartz Composer screen saver

Tags: macos, video, screensaver, quartz-composer

I am working on Quartz Composer Screen Saver, Using One animated video which i created. I used Movie Importer Patch for this. in movie location set the video location and connected the image with  another patch 'Resize Image If in Preview'.

the screen saver created and it works fine in my machine. what i want is how can i embed this video that the screen saver can work in other machin. right now if i change the video name or location then screen saver not working, nor i can send to other machine to view the screen.

is there any way that i can user remote location of video, like i will host video on my server use that http path in movie location path.. i tried this but its not working.

need help in this either to embed video or to use remote video location to run the screen saver.!

[Quartz Composer for screen saver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eenkc.png)

Answer (score 0):

ok, i find solution by my own, host video on remote server and use that http path in movie import location. in my case issue was that the video file was .mp4 but was not proper mp4, so i converted video properly and then start working.